# How to resolve the closed stream error?

Tags: java

I tried to print the PartnerDetails of Id 3 with the following code:

```
JSONObject a=pHelper.getPartnerDetails("3");
System.out.println("obj"+a);
```

I got the following error message:

```
Results :
Failed tests: linkTest(mobileweb.Link.LinkTest): Attempted read from closed stream.
```

Comment: What does `pHelper.getPartnerDetails("3");` do?

Comment: Do you really think this non-existing context is enough to explain what you try to do?

Comment: I separated the code from the error message, to make the question clearer. It looks like additional code is still required in order to answer your question, since the error indicates you are attempting to read from a closed stream, so you should include the code that initializes the stream you are reading from. It would also help to know how is `pHelper` declared and initialized.

Comment: @Eran The problem got resloved actually,i tried to read the response multiple times, which  caused the issue .

Answer (score 0):

`linkTest` this stream is closed and that might be used in `getPartnerDetails(String str)` method. don't read or write data after closing the stream.